# Onvif compatibility

Tags: onvif

I have been using Onvif for one month and I am able to receive stream URI and have the control over all the configuration stuff from my own client program designed in C#.

In my application I want to take the videos (1 or 2 min streams) from 10 IP Cameras and then create a 10 min video. So it is like embedding the videos from all cameras.

My question is - Can I use Onvif for this application ?

I am asking because I only found information about configuration stuff in all Onvif WSDL files. So I got a doubt whether I can use or not. Kindly requesting you to tell me the compatibility of Onvif with my specified application. I would be more glad if you also provide some information on how to make it possible.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, which C# library do you use to control / edit the IP camera configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Onvif to configure the cameras for use with the application, however you would not use Onvif to actually acquire the video from the cameras.

You can use Onvif to configure the streams (Encoding format, multicast setup, network configuration, etc) and get the Uri for the stream ([GetSreamUri](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl#op.GetStreamUri)), but you would then need to access the RTSP streams directly to get the actual video.

This can be done using something like [ffdshow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/) with [Direct Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to grab the video from each camera and make a compilation.

Onvif has a [Streaming Specification](http://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v210.pdf) which describes how compliant cameras must implement streaming but it still results in the camera producing a video stream on the network. How clients end up acquiring the video is outside the scope of the specification.